# C++ code with explicit casting, crashing Visual Studio compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I've installed Visual Studio 2013 to try some C++ code to test an idea of classes that mutate themselves into other classes and stuff like that (it's stupid but the idea came in a dream) and it is crashing visual studio's compiler, have no idea why.

Just by compiling it, a crash message with the title "Microsft C++ Optimizer deixou de funcionar" (stopped running in my language)

Code:

```
class F
{
    public:

        int f;

        F(int f){   this->f = f; }
        operator A(){   return A(f); }
        operator P(){   return P(f); }
};

class A
{
    public:

        int a;

        A(int a){   this->a = a; }
        operator F(){   return F(a); }
        operator P(){   return P(a); }
};

class P
{
    public:
        int p;

        P(int p){   this->p = p; }
        operator F(){   return F(p); }
        operator A(){   return A(p); }
};

void stuff(F f)
{
    printf("Val -> %d\n", f.f);
}

void main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    P p(3);
    stuff((F)(A)(P)(F)(A)(P)(F)(A)p);
}
```

Comment: Are you trolling with the class names, or were they seriously selected at random?

Comment: I lol'ed at the `stuff((F)(A)(P)(F)(A)(P)(F)(A)p);` code line.

Comment: Looks like a trolling C++ fake question

Comment: If it could be L(O(L())) it would have been funnier

Comment: `void main` is not valid C++.

Comment: The classnames are F,A,P those are the first letters in my native language for some common words. I'm not joking, try it yourself and see that it crashes.

Comment: Abyx, that has nothing to do with it. I changed to void just to remove the return to post here with one line less. It crashes both ways.

Comment: It's Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate. Not downloaded via torrent, I have a key from the university.

Comment: It's never a good idea to turn valid code into an invalid one just for posting. And you don't need a `return` even in `int main`. Anyway, FWIW, it compiles fine with VS2010 (once I add forward declarations and move the bodies below all class definitions to make it legal C++)

Comment: Perhaps you could post some code that compiles, and reproduces the error? After I shuffle the code around to fix the compiler errors, there's no runtime error.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to build it with gcc. No crashing, just no building either..
That is *never* going to work. It's way too late to even bother trying to unravel what you've tried to accomplish. Here's the error messages:

```
||=== 001-forumQuestion, Release ===|
C:\Users\enhzflep\Documents\code\001-forumQuestion\main.cpp|11|error: expected type-specifier before 'A'|
C:\Users\enhzflep\Documents\code\001-forumQuestion\main.cpp|12|error: expected type-specifier before 'P'|
C:\Users\enhzflep\Documents\code\001-forumQuestion\main.cpp|23|error: expected type-specifier before 'P'|
C:\Users\enhzflep\Documents\code\001-forumQuestion\main.cpp|41|error: '::main' must return 'int'|
C:\Users\enhzflep\Documents\code\001-forumQuestion\main.cpp||In function 'int main(int, char**)':|
C:\Users\enhzflep\Documents\code\001-forumQuestion\main.cpp|44|error: no matching function for call to 'P::P(F)'|
C:\Users\enhzflep\Documents\code\001-forumQuestion\main.cpp|44|note: candidates are:|
C:\Users\enhzflep\Documents\code\001-forumQuestion\main.cpp|31|note: P::P(int)|
C:\Users\enhzflep\Documents\code\001-forumQuestion\main.cpp|31|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'F' to 'int'|
C:\Users\enhzflep\Documents\code\001-forumQuestion\main.cpp|26|note: P::P(const P&)|
C:\Users\enhzflep\Documents\code\001-forumQuestion\main.cpp|26|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'F' to 'const P&'|
||=== Build finished: 5 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds) ===|
```

Comment: It doesn't take too much fixing (just reorganisation, really) to make it build.

Comment: If you can't be bothered to answer the question, why post an answer?

Comment: @MikeSeymour - please, take another look at the original post. There actually wasn't a question asked. It was stated that it crashed the compiler, so I simply posted the errors that my one gave me.

Comment: @enhzflep: The question is clearly "Why is it crashing, and how can I fix it?", even if it wasn't explicitly spelled out. This doesn't answer any question.

Comment: No, it isn't - you _perceive_ or _imagine_ that the question is "Why is it crashing and how can I fix it." - no explicit question = no question. As I said, it crashed the OPs compiler - so I posted the error messages that mine gave - something not even the OPs compiler helped with. If you're still not reading straight, I couldn't post the messages in a comment. Don't like it? Vote me down if it makes you feel better. I really don't care. The tool-tip is after all "This answer is not useful".